# Can't update Visual studio enterprise Update 2 with update 3

Tags: visual-studio

When I try to update visual studio 2015 update 2 with update 3. The installer takes a while, but at the end it pops up the the attached errors. I have confirmed that the shell is installed on my machine. am on windows 10 enterprise

[image: When I try to update visual studio 2015 update 2 with update 3. The installer takes a while, but at the end it pops up the the attached errors. I have confirmed that the shell is installed on my machine. am on windows 10 enterprise]

Comment: click on "log files" and share the logs files

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the 2015 update 2 running, try this:

- Close VS Setup (if it is running)
- Go to “Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features”.
- Double click the “Microsoft Visual Studio 2015” entry.
- Choose “Modify”. VS Setup will download the latest list of optionally installable content.
- At the top of the list of optional items you should see “Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (New)”. Check it and click the Update button to install VSUpdate 3.